# How to enable scrolling in sap.m.Table in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

I have implemented `sap.m.Table` but all the records are not displayed. Also there seems to be no option for scrolling. I went through the [API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#constructor) which suggests using `growing`, `growingThreshold`, `growingScrollToLoad` of `sap.m.ListBase`.

Here **growing** would enable the table control to load more items, `growingThreshold` would determine the number of items to be requested from the model for each grow and `getGrowingScrollToLoad` would enable the user to scroll through the records instead of a **more** button being displayed to load more data.

However, even after using these properties my entire data is still not getting rendered and I can see that more button instead of scroll bar. Below the **more** button I am able to see a number that determines the entire number of records to be rendered as well and the number of records that have been rendered in the initial view.

Shouldn't scrolling be a default option if the data exceeds a page's limit? I'm very confused. Please help.

Also I did go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260077/scrolling-in-sap-m-table) post! :)

Comment: Try to click on the 'more' button, does it not load more data to the table?

Comment: hi @Jaro no it doesn't load the entire data. only the data that can be displayed on the page

Comment: May be this occurs based on your parent container. If you use a `layout:fixContent` as container the scrolling behavior of the table could be  affected.

Answer (score 7):

Update 8-March-2019 :

There is now a new way to enable scrolling in `sap.m.Table` with sticky option.
Kindly check the API and samples for more example. This new way is recommended and support and development is provided directly via the library.

Check: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/setSticky

---

Old Answer:

Given how the question is beautifully setup, with options:

1. `sap.ui.table.Table` : scrollable with fixed Header.
2. `sap.m.Table`: growing list, scrollable WITHOUT fixed header.

But many a times we need a **`sap.m.Table`- scrollable but with static header**, so the content below the table does not move further below. This below code will help during that time. It has a scrollable body with fixed header.

**Setup**: I'm using two `sap.m.Table` instances, one just with header and other just for data. Also, I'm using a scrollable container, which holds the 2nd table  (without the header). Because of the fixed width of Scrollable container, we see a scrollbar. Dummy code is provided below:

**View.xml:**

```
<Table showNoData='false'>
            <columns>
                <Column>
                    <header>
                        <Text text='ID' />
                    </header>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <header>
                        <Text text='First Name' />
                    </header>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <header>
                        <Text text='Last Name'  />
                    </header>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <header>
                        <Text text='Gender' />
                    </header>
                </Column>
            </columns>
        </Table>
        <ScrollContainer height='20rem' vertical='true'> <!-- To have fixed with and enable vertical scrolling of data table -->
        <!-- Table to hold data, data ,data -->
            <Table class='tableHdr' items='{/}'> <!--  CSS class to hide the column header, otherwise we will have 2 headers. -->
                <columns>
                <!-- Dont need columns header, as upper table has already defined them. -->
                    <Column >
                    </Column>
                    <Column >
                    </Column>
                    <Column >
                    </Column>
                    <Column >
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                        <cells>
                            <Text text='{id}' />
                            <Text text='{first_name}' />
                            <Text text='{last_name}' />
                            <Text text='{gender}' />

                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
        </ScrollContainer>
```

Now, If you execute the above code without this below style class, you will end up with 2 columns headers from 2 tables. So, to remove the 2nd Column header, I used the below class:

```
.tableHdr .sapMListTblHeaderCell {
            padding: 0rem;
}
```

Would like to hear the feedback on this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if there are more rows in `sap.m.Table`, scrolling will be there.
You can see the [working example here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview)

But if you want to force to fixed rows visibility, you can use [`sap.ui.table.Table`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Resizing/preview) with the properties `visibleRowCount` and `minAutoRowCount`.

Also note that if the vertical scrollbar is not visible for `sap.m.Table`, check if some other css is overriding the style. Else you can paste the code in the question with full ui code.